# Redirect apache with path to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For example, I have olddomain.com and newdomain.com

I would like to redirect:

- *olddomain.com* to *newdomain.com*,
- *olddomain.com/if-theres-a-path to* *newdomain.com/backup/if-theres-a-path*

I've been trying several config but not working, last one the I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/backup/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://newdomain.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use the leading slash in RewriteRule pattern if you are using these rules in an htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://newdomain.com/ [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/backup/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Clear your browser's cache before testing this Redirect.**

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried to change my domain on AWS:

```
1) Register new domain then wait a few days 
2) Route 53 > DNS Management   
3) Created hosted zone  
4) Config your domain record to point to the server :D
```

Comment: I'm using dreamhost. Control panel a little bit limited what can be configured and doesn't support the case. Changing `.htaccess` take effect immediately and doesn't need to wait.